# Player Buffer remains at 0 but the videoElement Buffer changes?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am using a custom receiver and a MPL. I am performing a live dash streaming.
As some of the segments are downloaded the HTML video Element buffer is updated but the player's buffer remains at 0. Why does this happen? How can I solve it?

Comment: Without a sample stream, it won't be able to debug your issue. Please file a issue with a sample stream: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: The issue was caused by a missing parameter in the mpd file ie, MPD@mediaPresentationDuration. However, I would like to know why MPL was reacting so, when other player(bitmovin, shaka) consumed the manifest without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by adding a parameter to the manifest.

```
MPD@mediaPresentationDuration
```

But some other player have played the content from same manifest without any trouble.